# How to Reorganize Query Results in SQL using Pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a query that returns data that looks like this:

```
Project Name   Analyte   Result

A                 BOD       4mg/l

A              COD       10mg/l

B              BOD       4mg/l

B              COD       10mg/l
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
Project Name   Analyte   Result   Analyte  Result

A              BOD       4mg/l        COD      10mg/l

B              BOD       4mg/l        COD      10mg/l
```

I can't figure out how to do this with sql. Will the pivot function do this? How?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you always going to have one `BOD` and one `COD`?  This looks like a `JOIN`, not a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are always going to have one `BOD` and one `COD`:

```
SELECT
  [a].[Project Name],
  [a].[Analyte] AS [Analyte1],
  [a].[Result] AS [Result1],
  [b].[Analyte] AS [Analyte2],
  [b].[Result] AS [Result2]
FROM
  [Results] [a]
  JOIN [Results] [b]
    ON [a].[Project Name] = [b].[Project Name]
WHERE
  [a].[Analyte] = 'BOD'
  AND [b].[Analyte] = 'COD';
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29b037/2).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what RDBMS you are using but you can easily use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select
  projectName,
  max(case when Analyte = 'BOD' then Analyte end) Analyte_BOD,
  max(case when Analyte = 'BOD' then Result end) Result_BOD,
  max(case when Analyte = 'COD' then Analyte end) Analyte_COD,
  max(case when Analyte = 'COD' then Result end) Result_COD
from yourtable
group by projectname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/823bd/1)